# BigQuery: Atomically replace a date partition using DML

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I often want to load one day's worth of data into a date-partitioned BigQuery table, replacing any data that's already there.  I know how to do this for 'old-style' data partitioned tables (the ones that have a `_PARTITIONTIME` field) but don't know how to do this with the new-style date-partitioned tables (which use a normal date/timestamp column to specify the partitioning because they don't allow one to use the `$` decorator.

Let's say I want to do this on `my_table`.  With old-style date-partitioned tables, I accomplished this using a load job that utilized the `$` decorator and the `WRITE_TRUNCATE` write disposition -- e.g., I'd set the destination table to be `my_table$20181005`.

However, I'm not sure how to perform the equivalent operation using a DML.  I find myself performing separate `DELETE` and `INSERT` commands.  This isn't great because it increases complexity, the number of queries, and the operation isn't atomic.

I want to know how to do this using the `MERGE` command to keep this all contained within a single, atomic operation.  However I can't wrap my head around the MERGE command's syntax and haven't found an example for this use case.  Does anyone know how this should be done?

**The ideal answer would** be a DML statement that selected all columns from `source_table` and inserted it into the `2018-10-05` date partition of `my_table`, deleting any existing data that was in `my_table`'s `2018-10-05` date partition.  We can assume that `source_table` and `my_table` have the same schemas, and that `my_table` is partitioned on the `day` column, which is of type `DATE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> because they don't allow one to use the $ decorator

But they do--you can use `table_name$YYYYMMDD` when you load into column-based partitioned table as well. For example, I made a partitioned table:

```
$ bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "CREATE TABLE tmp_elliottb.PartitionedTable (x INT64, y NUMERIC, date DATE) PARTITION BY date"
```

Then I loaded into a specific partition:

```
$ echo "1,3.14,2018-11-07" > row.csv
$ bq load "tmp_elliottb.PartitionedTable\$20181107" ./row.csv
```

I tried to load into the wrong partition for the input data, and received an error:

```
$ echo "1,3.14,2018-11-07" > row.csv
$ bq load "tmp_elliottb.PartitionedTable\$20181105" ./row.csv
Some rows belong to different partitions rather than destination partition 20181105
```

I then replaced the data for the partition:

```
$ echo "2,0.11,2018-11-07" > row.csv
$ bq load --replace "tmp_elliottb.PartitionedTable\$20181107" ./row.csv
```

Yes, you can use `MERGE` as a way of replacing data for a partitioned table's partition, but you can also use a load job.

Comment: Thanks!  I went back and looked at why I thought this wasn't possible, and it was because of an error message I got from Airflow (which in this case doesn't accurately reflect the BigQuery API).  This solution is much better than DML for my use-case because it handles the case where schemas are additively updated over time (and thus inconsistent), which I can't seem to handle with the DML because it requires me to explicitly list out all the columns I'm going to insert into a table.

Comment: @conradlee so how did you manage to update the BQ table with new data using Airflow operator? I have a scenario where my existing table is partitioned by a DATE column and my incremental load brings in data for the past three days which when trying to load the data fails with error 

```Exception: BigQuery job failed. Final error was: {'reason': 'invalid', 'message':    'Some rows belong to different partitions rather than destination partition 20191202'}```

Any help on this is very much appreciated

Comment: hi, can you add the DML that will perform the delete and insert operations in the partitioned table, for several partitions?